# Simplifying expressions involving Divisible

Tags: simplifying-expressions, number-theory

```
FullSimplify[ Divisible[p^2 - 1, 24] , Element[p, Primes] && p > 3]
```

Should evaluate to `True`, but I get

> ```
> Divisible[-1 + p^2, 24]
> ```

Compare with

```
FullSimplify[Divisible[(6 k - 1)^2 - 1, 24], k \[Element] Integers]
```

Which does evaluate to

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Actually you can show a much simpler case for `Divisible`: Try this: `Assuming[Element[p, Primes] && p > 3, Divisible[p, 2]]` I think  Divisible works only for *actual* numbers. From help it says : `works for integers or rational number` but this is my educated guess ;)